# adding column from another file

Tags: linux, bash, shell, csv

I am pretty new in BASH scripting. I have a csv file with 2 columns separated by comma.

```
ASDP01,01989015064
KSDP03,01988683270
KSDP06,01945993069
CSDP11,01990721863
CSDP13,01955883155
ASDP12,01953889744
CSDP11,01956798684
ASDP11,01959969994
KSDP01,01924824056
```

I want to add 2 more columns from another text file.
this is written in the text file:

```
662,2016-12-31
```

after adding from the tex file, the csv file will be like below

```
ASDP01,01989015064,662,2016-12-31
KSDP03,01988683270,662,2016-12-31
KSDP06,01945993069,662,2016-12-31
CSDP11,01990721863,662,2016-12-31
CSDP13,01955883155,662,2016-12-31
ASDP12,01953889744,662,2016-12-31
CSDP11,01956798684,662,2016-12-31
ASDP11,01959969994,662,2016-12-31
KSDP01,01924824056,662,2016-12-31
```

can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Whichever of the n solutions that you would be able to use, each would probably ask you to create a new file.

Comment: I want to create a new csv file after adding columns.

Comment: paste -d ',' file1 file2 > file3

Comment: You haven't mentioned if there is an entry in file2 corresponding to each entry in file1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume `file2.csv` contains only one row with `662,2016-12-31`.

```
string="$(cat file2.csv)"
sed 's/.*/&,'"$string"'/' file1.csv > new.csv
```

Output to new.csv:

```
ASDP01,01989015064,662,2016-12-31
KSDP03,01988683270,662,2016-12-31
KSDP06,01945993069,662,2016-12-31
CSDP11,01990721863,662,2016-12-31
CSDP13,01955883155,662,2016-12-31
ASDP12,01953889744,662,2016-12-31
CSDP11,01956798684,662,2016-12-31
ASDP11,01959969994,662,2016-12-31
KSDP01,01924824056,662,2016-12-31
```

---

See: [The Stack Overflow Regular Expressions FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22944075/3776858)

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish the results using `awk` too.

```
#cat file1
KSDP01,01989015064
KSDP03,01988683270
KSDP06,01945993069
CSDP11,01990721863
CSDP13,01955883155
ASDP12,01953889744
CSDP11,01956798684
ASDP11,01959969994
KSDP01,01924824056

#cat file2
662,2016-12-31

#awk -v f2content="$(<file2)" '{$0=($0 "," f2content)}1' file1
KSDP01,01989015064,662,2016-12-31
KSDP03,01988683270,662,2016-12-31
KSDP06,01945993069,662,2016-12-31
CSDP11,01990721863,662,2016-12-31
CSDP13,01955883155,662,2016-12-31
ASDP12,01953889744,662,2016-12-31
CSDP11,01956798684,662,2016-12-31
ASDP11,01959969994,662,2016-12-31
KSDP01,01924824056,662,2016-12-31
```

See [[ awk concatenation ]](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Concatenation.html).

Answer (score 0):

another `sed` alternative

```
$ sed 's/$/,'"$(cat file2)"'/' file1
```